# How to connect a WorkManager to a specific restful web service?

Tags: java, rest, configuration, weblogic, workmanagers

I have a wls server where there are several web applications deployed. One of these web applications contain a restful web service which can take a long time to execute. Therefore I want it to have a custom WorkManager that can handle threads which otherwhise are considered stuck. As I understand you can set a work manager for a specific ejb by using xpath to point at its dispatch policy, like this

'/weblogic-ejb-jar/weblogic-enterprise-bean/[ejb-name="anEJB"]/dispatch-policy'

Is there a way to do this for restful web services, i.e. set the workmanager for a specific web service (or web application) and not all of the applications which are deployed on the same wls? The examples I have found only does this globally.

The WLS version I am using is 10.3.6

Comment: Have you tried using an application scoped work manager? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/config_wls/self_tuned.html#wp1066991 It should be more or less the same as for an EJB

Comment: Thanks. Managed to create a WorkManager in weblogic.xml and then set it to the servlet in web.xml